Flutter app not launching properly for android device
Getting error while running the flutter app. Tried creating new virtual device but still same issue.
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/flutter/flutter_embedding_debug/1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f/flutter_embedding_debug-1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve io.flutter:flutter_embedding_debug:1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.

         > Could not get resource 'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/io/flutter/x86_64_debug/1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f/x86_64_debug-1.0.0-b8800d88be4866db1b15f8b954ab2573bba9960f.pom'.
            



It was a proxy issue since I was using the company laptop. After turning off the internet security in zscaler it worked fine.

Android Build gradle file
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<Latest_Version>'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-<Latest_Version>-all.zip

after
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade


I followed the below steps but still same issue :
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade


new error now
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Where:
project/flutter_projects/expense_tracker/android/settings.gradle' line: 22


What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:



I'll check this in depth
